# Regex to find all URLs in a string that contains a substring AND don't contain another

Tags: python, regex

I managed to filter all URLs out of this string:

```
hi, this is your link (but this one is bad formatted and useless):

https://www.test.comhttps://app.test.com/a/b/c/5e20bed422e7880012ba8acc/next?param=1?locale=2

but there is a good link too:

https://app.test.com/a/b/c/5e20bed422e7880012ba8acc/next?param=1?locale=2

and there are also other irrelevant links:

http://www.google.com
http://test.test.com
```

with this RegEx

```
http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

After playing with it around for a while, I am stuck trying to undestand how to tweak it and get only:

```
https://www.test.com/a/b/c/5e20bed422e7880012ba8acc/next?param=1?locale=2
```

What would be the simplest way to filter out URLs that contain '/next?' but not 'comhttps'?

thanks a bunch!

Comment: A quick solution would be to check if the end string ($) is locale=2, but that depends if all your string are like that.

Comment: Aren't there specialized libraries for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
\bhttps?://(?=[\w.]*/)(?:(?!https?://).)*
```

It finds the correct url and rejects the others from your example.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/aE5tjs/4)

---

```
import re

body_text = '''
hi, this is your link (but this one is bad formatted and useless):

https://www.test.comhttps://app.test.com/a/b/c/5e20bed422e7880012ba8acc/next?param=1?locale=2

but there is a good link too:

https://app.test.com/a/b/c/5e20bed422e7880012ba8acc/next?param=1?locale=2

and there are also other irrelevant links:

http://www.google.com
http://test.test.com
'''
url = re.findall(r"\bhttps?://(?=[\w.]*/)(?:(?!https?://).)*", body_text)
print url
```

**Output:**

```
['https://app.test.com/a/b/c/5e20bed422e7880012ba8acc/next?param=1?locale=2']
```

Comment: @MartR: You missed the multiline flag `m` at the end, look at the diffrence between my regex101 link and yours.

Comment: @MartR: New version without `m` flag.

Comment: brilliant! thanks - btw, the text of your message should read: 'It finds the valid url and reject all others from your example.'

Comment: @MartR: You're welcome, glad it helps. Text edited.

Comment: sorry to be such a bore :) just one more doubt: I am trying to use your RegEx like this:
`url = re.findall(r"\bhttps?://(?=[\w.]*/)(?:(?!https?://).)*", body_text)`
but I get no results. what am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: @MartR: I've added piece of code with your sample text.  If you have more complex text, edit your question and add real text and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```regex
(https?:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6})(?=https?)(\S+)
```

We'll use the `i` flag for a case insensitive search.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/J62XZq/2

#### Explanation

- `https?:\/\/` is to look for *http://* or *https://*
- `[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}` is to look for a valid domain name. I did not check if it was really totally bullet proof. But it seems not to bad. We could maybe find an official regular expression to validate domain names. The `(?:)` group is a non-capturing group (if we don't need it).
- `(https?:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6})` is both together and captured in a group so that we have the original URL.
- `(?=https?)` is a positive lookahead so that the domain before must be followed by http or https. You may need to adapt it if you can have ftp or other protocols.
- `(\S+)` is to match non-spaces one or more times and capture it in a group (for later use and processing. This second group will have to be processed in order to get rid of the second query string `?param=x&option` which probably belongs to the surounding URL.

#### Edit

Since we had a discussion about only matching the correct ones it means that my answer isn't really the good one. It's not always easy to understand what has to be done.

https://regex101.com/r/J62XZq/7

Here, we look for URLs with a domain which is not followed by `http:` or `https:`.

The trick is to add the `\b` at the beginning to avoid matching the URL inside the URL and to use a negative lookahead after the domain.

```regex
\bhttps?:\/\/[a-z0-9]+(?:[\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}(?!https?:)\/\S+\/next\?(\S+)
```

The negative lookahead is done with `(?!https?:)` (I didn't add the double slash as I assume it's enough).

The last part with the `/next` might not be necessary. This depends if you want to match URL specificly with that inside or not.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! this regex is filtering out only the bad link (the first one, which contains that 'comhttps'). Is there a way to filter it out, all in a single expression?

Comment: @MartR Well, just activate the replacement of the full match by nothing and it will be striped out of your content. See here: https://regex101.com/r/J62XZq/3

Comment: @MartR Haaa, I see, you want to find the valid links only? is it that?

Comment: thanks! I am not sure what you meant by 'activate the replacement of the full match by nothing', so I gotta go back to the books :)

Comment: yes, I would like to have only the valid link `https://app.test.com/a/b/c/5e20bed422e7880012ba8acc/next?param=1?locale=2`

Comment: @MartR Do the valid links have a special format? Is it the hash in the middle that is the marker to find them?

Comment: These are thet two possible formats:
`https://app.test.com/a/next?locale=en-US&project_id=5e0f09da9b7e97001ce4cf36

https://app.test.com/a/view/5e1548583189980001736d77/next?locale=en-US`

both contain `/next?`

Comment: What about trying this? https://regex101.com/r/J62XZq/5
It should correct the corrupted links. It seems that a part is ok so why not keeping them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207204/discussion-between-mart-r-and-patrick-janser).